# Ruby PG conn.exec_params SQL structure

Tags: sql, ruby, connection, pg

I'm getting an error on a simple statement through PG:

```
require 'pg'
conn = PG.connect( dbname: 'myDB' )
@res = conn.exec_params( 'SELECT count(id) FROM users WHERE username = $1 AND status = "active"', ['johnny5'] )
```

The error:

```
/Users/rich/app.rb:14:in `exec_params': ERROR:  column "active" does not exist (PG::UndefinedColumn)
LINE 1: ...unt(id) FROM users WHERE username = $1 AND status = "active"
                                                               ^
```

"active" is a field value, not a column.

My question:  I have fixed this by entering the value "active" as another placeholder.  Are quoted values in the SQL not permitted?  I assumed that quoted aspects of the SQL would have been fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String literals in SQL use sigle quotes, double quotes are for identifiers (such as table and column names). So, when you mention `"active"`, the database complains that there is no such column.

The solution is to use a placeholder:

```
@res = conn.exec_params(
  %q{SELECT count(id) FROM users WHERE username = $1 AND status = $2},
  ['johnny5', 'active']
)
```

or use single quotes inside the SQL:

```
@res = conn.exec_params(
  %q{SELECT count(id) FROM users WHERE username = $1 AND status = 'active'},
  ['johnny5']
)
```

Switching from `'...'` to `%q{...}` for your SQL string literal makes the internal quoting problems a bit easier to deal with.

Comment: "String literals in SQL use sigle quotes" - that completely depends on the flavour of SQL, but true for Postgres.

Comment: @TimTisdall Perhaps I should qualify that as "Standard SQL". I'm not aware of any flavour that doesn't allow single quotes for string literals.

Comment: Yeah, I think they all use single quotes for string literals.  I was specifically thinking the opposite way where some use _other_ things for string literals, such as MySQL which uses both single and double quotes for string literals.

Comment: @TimTisdall And some use `[]` or backticks for quoted identifiers where "standard" SQL uses double quotes, some let you get away with almost anything. So many standards to choose from :)